# Read 'Binary' files with ReadFile WinAPI

Tags: c++, file, winapi, readfile

When I try to open '.exe' files with `ReadFile()` Windows API, It's just return the 2 first character of file like : `MZ`

Here is my Code:

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 5000

VOID CALLBACK FileIOCompletionRoutine(
__in  DWORD dwErrorCode,
__in  DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
__in  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);

VOID CALLBACK FileIOCompletionRoutine(
__in  DWORD dwErrorCode,
__in  DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
__in  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped)
{
   _tprintf(TEXT("Error code:\t%x\n"), dwErrorCode);
   _tprintf(TEXT("Number of bytes:\t%x\n"), dwNumberOfBytesTransfered);
   g_BytesTransferred = dwNumberOfBytesTransfered;
}

HANDLE hFile;
DWORD  dwBytesRead = 0;
char   ReadBuffer[BUFFERSIZE] = { 0 };
OVERLAPPED ol = { 0 };
hFile = CreateFile(fullFilePath.c_str(),               // file to open
    GENERIC_READ,          // open for reading
    FILE_SHARE_READ,       // share for reading
    NULL,                  // default security
    OPEN_EXISTING,         // existing file only
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, // normal file
    NULL);                 // no attr. template

ReadFileEx(hFile, ReadBuffer, BUFFERSIZE - 1, &ol, FileIOCompletionRoutine);
```

When I print `ReadBuffer` It's just `MZ`(exe file).

But Using:

```
std::ifstream file(argv[1], std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
```

It's work perfectly.
How Can I Read Binary files With ReadFile?

Comment: How do you print `ReadBuffer`? As a NUL-terminated string, I suspect. Which of course it is not.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I put the value of `ReadBuffer` to String and print string using `std::cout`

Comment: Precisely. You print it as if it were text data, but it's binary data. It probably has a zero byte right after `MZ`, and the printing stops there.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I think so because when I open EXE file with notepad it's `NULL` after MZ. How can I ignore `NULL` characters ? or remove it?

Comment: rather than `std::string val{buffer};` use `std::string val{buffer, buffer+dwBytesRead};`

Comment: Why do you want to print binary data in the first place? What was the original point of the exercise - why did you decide to read an EXE file? What goal do you pursue? Do you have a problem achieving that goal?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik My goal is to find a Data in any file or folder. So I should able to open executable files too.

Comment: Please note that looking for data in binary files  is tricky if the data is a string. The text in a binary file may be in arbitrary encoding: utf-8, utf-16, Windows-specific.

Comment: You know it's a binary file. Which means it is not text. In fact that's precisely what a binary file is. So don't treat it as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with reading, the problem is with printing.

You're not showing your code, but you're likely trying to print with `printf` or something similar. IOW, you're printing it as C string.

Well, binary data includes 0s, and in this case the first 3 bytes are 'M', 'Z', '\0' - and that prints as a null-terminated string "MZ".

You'd have to write a converter to per-byte hex numbers if you want to see meaningful printing of binary data: `4D 5A 00` and so on

Comment: Something like String(or `ReadBuffer`) to hex converter?

Comment: `ReadBuffer`, definitely `ReadBuffer`. `void *buffer, int readSize`

Comment: std::string(const char*, size_t) will also serve to pass binary data around.

Answer (score 0):

> How Can I Read Binary files With ReadFile?

`ReadFile` (and `ReadFileEx` ) works 'in binary mode'. You get exact file contents byte by byte without any translation.

You have problem with writing/printing. This mostly depends where you want to write, but for outputing (binary) data potentially containing nulls in C++ choose `write` method

```
some_output_stream.write( buffer_ptr, num_bytes_in_buffer );
```

`some_output_stream` should be set to binary mode (std::ios::binary). Without this flag all bytes with value 10 could be translated to pairs 13,10.

If C FILE functions are used

```
fwrite( buffer_ptr, 1, num_bytes_in_buffer, some_output_file );
```

Again `some_output_file` has to be in binary mode.

In some scenarios `WriteFile` can be used complementary to your usage of `ReadFile`.